# Laravel Squash Migrate Error pg_dump not found

Tags: laravel, postgresql, migration, squash

i have 3 container (php-fpm, nginx, postgresql) for my laravel app, i execute command php artisan schema:dump on php-fpm container and I found error pg_dump not found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had similar issue but with `mysql`. What solved it for me was an installation of `mysql-client` inside the container in which I was trying to execute `php artisan schema:dump` command (I have added `RUN apt-get install -y mysql-client` inside my `Dockerfile`, then I have rebuilt all the containers). I think that you need to do similar thing, e.g. `RUN apt-get install -y postgresql-client` inside your Dockerfile.